# Can we find the number of threads executing in an application and process/functions getting executed

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa-touch

I have a legacy application where there are multiple threads getting spawned every minute for various sync processes. 
 I want to check the number of threads getting executed in the application at any point of time, types of thread(ex: main, background, global queue) and the process associated with each thread in IOS.

Could you please tell me if we can do the same in xCode or Instruments?

Comment: If you're running your app with Xcode attached, you can do this interactively by pausing the app and examining the current threads in the  Debug Navigator.

Comment: @PhillipMills: We can get the number of threads and type of threads getting executed. Can we get the process or block of code getting executed on this threads ?

Comment: Sure.  Try it.  You should see a stack trace of what's executing on each thread.  If you would rather have it in text form, you can also type "bt all" in the debug console.